# Using Backbone.js to handle browser history

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history

I'm trying to use Backbone.js to handle the browser history. I'm not setting up Views / Models because I don't want it to handle this, and probably because of this I'm not getting it to work properly.

At this point my page is changing urls. Like:

```
domain.com/services
domain.com/products
domain.com/contact
domain.com/gallery
domain.com/gallery/photo1
```

The problem is: if I try to reload the page at domain.com/gallery/photo1. I get the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

All other pages with just one level permalink works properly on reload. Am I missing something on Backbone?

I'm just using Backbone.Router and Backbone.history.

Is there any simple tutorial on how to set up a site with backbone.js? Just the history thing?

Here's my script:

```
var Router;
var myRouter;

$(document).ready(function(){
    Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize : function(options) {
            //
        },
        routes: {
            '' : 'home',
            '*actions' : 'pages'
        },
        home : function() {
            this.render('/');
        },
        pages : function(actions) {
            this.render(actions);
        },
        render : function(path) {
            var fullLine = '';
            path = (path === '/' || path === '')? '/' : path;
            console.log('path: ' + path);
        }
    });

    myRouter = new Router();

    Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
    Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/backbone_teste/"});

    // MENU CLICK
    $('.menu').children('li').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            myRouter.navigate($(this).attr('data-id'), true, true);
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" suggests that someone is trying to interpret HTML as JSON. Can you show us some code?

Comment: Post edited. I just added this options to emulateHTTP and emulateJSON to see if it solves the problem. I'm not loading anything yet. If I change pushState to false and try to access domain.com/#gallery/photo1 it works, but I don't want the hash! Thanks

Comment: I'm running this exemple on localhost/backbone_teste and I have an .htaccess file to mod_rewrite. Maybe this has something to do with my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved:

I just added to my index.php file the following code at the head section:

```
<base href="http://localhost/backbone_teste/" />
```

And it works.

Anyway I would like to know why this happens and why Backbone.js documentation don't mention this.

I found the solution at this link: [HTML5 History / pushState URLs, .htaccess and You](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/)

Thanks